# zomato Api doesn't return restaurants in search by aggregate_rating

Tags: search, zomato-api

I am building resturants search app and I want to filter restaurants in a city by many attributes like cuisines, category, aggregate_rating, price_range...
when I send request to Zomato Api like this :

https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=297&entity_type=city&cuisines=1

I get the rigth result and all restaurants that have cuisines=1(american cuisine).

but when I send another request and change query attributes like this:

https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=297&entity_type=city&aggregate_rating=3

I get restaurants without filtering by my query (aggregate_rating=3).
could any one help me?